# Solution of $\dot{c}(t)=c^2(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solute  $\dot{c}(t)=c^2(t)$  ?

I am not familiar with ODE, I want to present the solution by exponent,but fail.

Comment: **Hint:** Look up Separable Equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\frac{dc}{dt}=c^2$$
$$\int\frac{dc}{c^2}=\int dt$$
$$-\frac{1}{c}=t+K$$
$$c(t)=-\frac{1}{t+K}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
use the separable method 
$$\frac{dc}{c^2}=1dt$$